# Bootstrap a Sails.js app only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Is there a way to specify steps when `sails lift`ing an app, so that would be executed only *once* in the app until specified otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a file just for this purpose in projectname/config/bootstrap.js.

Comment: [The relevant documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-bootstrap) does not mention any such behavior. Can you point out where it's mentioned?

Comment: Sure, it's located [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-bootstrap).